# Xcode has encountered an unexpected error (0x01c)

Tags: xcode, xcode7

So, in Xcode 7, when I went to build an app onto my phone I got this error:

```
Xcode has encountered an unexpected error: (0x01c) No space left on device, at ‘/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-8167/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDeviceKitBase_Utilities.m:1151’
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Restarting Xcode did the trick for me

Answer (score 3):

My trick was:

1. Deleting some files due to there's only 1,8 MB space left on my Mac.
2. After deleting files, it was 1,5 GB space left on my Mac and I still can't build to device
3. Quit then restarting Xcode was completing those tricks above.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have no space left on your device. Try deleting something.

Comment: i did, and i have 2.9 gb left :(

Comment: Is your app larger than 2.9GB compiled?

Answer (score 0):

Deleted files from Mac to free up memory and quit Xcode. This worked for me.